# How to count number of times a name appears by month linked to a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find a formula that counts how many times a string appears depending on a `month()` value referred in a cell.

There's a quick example in the following image. The actual data table that I'm using is over 200,000 rows. I need to include the `month()` criteria as a dynamic value in order to get a different "Monthly Registry" every day/month.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Whenever it be possible add the sample data and formulas as text, not as images. Also add a a brief description of your search efforts to find helpful content from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image, I think this formula is more appropriate:

```
=query(A1:B,"select B,count(B) where month(A)+1= "& month(today()) &" group by B label count(B) 'Monthly Registry' ")
```

place it in `D1`

[image: query]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked + helped me to understand a new logic and use cases for the query function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  A1:B, 
  "select year(A), month(A)+1, B, count(B) 
   where A is not null 
   group by year(A), month(A)+1, B 
   label year(A) 'year', month(A)+1 'month' ", 
  1 
)
```